# How to remove protruding part of a square shape in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztGXq.png)

I would like to get a square shape from the right image above. But when I try to get it, it also includes other protruding parts because they have similar color. Are there any solutions to get the result like below? (The square lines are not 100 % straight. They are little distorted.)

[image]

This is the code I wrote.

```cpp
cv::Mat img_gray, img, clahe_img, threshold_img, bitwise_img,  morph_img;
cv::Mat rectified_CCD_img = cv::imread('img.png')

cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(99, 99, CV_8U);
clahe = cv::createCLAHE(10, cv::Size(100, 100)); 
cv::cvtColor(rectified_CCD_img, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::medianBlur(img_gray, img, 33);
clahe->apply(img, clahe_img);
cv::threshold(clahe_img, threshold_img, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
cv::bitwise_not(threshold_img, bitwise_img);
cv::morphologyEx(bitwise_img, morph_img, cv::MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
```

That's the original image:

[image]

[Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jH59oU83AJk09uOVzK95GOv-htBfJknl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide input images.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Sorry I forgot it. I uploaded the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific image my pipeline would be very simple:

1. Binary threshold the image with a fixed threshold. The rectangle is quite dark compared to the rest of the image.
2. Morphological opening with a large rectangular kernel to get rid of the "noise".
3. To get a perfect rectangle, determine the bounding rectangle of the remaining part, and draw a white rectangle.

That'd be the whole code:

```cpp
// Read image
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("OTH61.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// Binary threshold image at fixed threshold
cv::Mat img_thr;
cv::threshold(img, img_thr, 32, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

// Morphological opening with large rectangular kernel
cv::Mat img_mop;
cv::morphologyEx(img_thr, img_mop, cv::MORPH_OPEN, cv::Mat::ones(51, 51, CV_8UC1));

// Draw rectangle w.r.t. to the bounding rectangle of the remaining part
cv::rectangle(img_mop, cv::boundingRect(img_mop), 255, cv::FILLED);
```

The thresholded image:

[image: Thresholded image]

The morphological opened image:

[image: Opened image]

The cleaned image:

[image: Cleaned image]

Comment: Thank you so much. However, if there is different environment such as different light, it there any adaptive way to change the parameters for the threshold?

Comment: Hard to tell without additional example images. If your rectangle becomes as bright as the background for example, then, of course, thresholding might fail in general. Maybe, instead of using thresholding, other approaches like edge detection can be helpful, too, then. Nevertheless, the focus here was on the proper extraction of the rectangle in the masked image. If you have difficulties with the proper extraction of the rectangle in the original image, please [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a separate question on that, because that's something completely different.

Comment: I understand. I will think about ways to solve the problem. Thank you!